# Converting several factor columns with thousand-separator values to integers using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

Cannot find the exact solution on SO and anyway would like the most succinct version using the tidyverse set of R packages. Want all but the first column to be integers and to cater for many more columns in a real-life scenario

```
df <- structure(list(col_1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"
), class = "factor"), col_2 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1,234", 
"23", "4,567"), class = "factor"), col_3 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1234", 
"46", "6,789"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("col_1", "col_2", 
"col_3"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mutate_at`, exclude the first column, use `gsub` to remove commas and then convert them to integers:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate_at(.cols = -1, funs(as.integer(gsub(",", "", .))))

#  col_1 col_2 col_3
#1     a  1234  1234
#2     b  4567    46
#3     c    23  6789
```

---

Another option with `parse_number`, this gives numeric columns though:

```
df %>% mutate_at(.cols = -1, funs(parse_number))

#  col_1 col_2 col_3
#1     a  1234  1234
#2     b  4567    46
#3     c    23  6789
```

Comment: To be truly hadleyversish, surely you'd use stringr instead of gsub, eh. There is likely some alternative to as.integer by now, too.

Comment: Just realized that if you use the write_csv(df,"test.csv") and the df <- read_csv("test.csv") to get the data back this also guesses correctly that the first col is character and rest are numeric

Answer (score 1):

looking for a `","` in the columns, if present making that column numeric :

```
df1 = lapply(df, function(x) {if(any(grepl(",", x))){x<-as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x))};x})
# as.data.frame(df1)
#  col_1 col_2 col_3
#1     a  1234  1234
#2     b  4567    46
#3     c    23  6789
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop through them with `lapply`, replace the `,` with blanks in `gsub`, convert to `integer` and assign (`:=`) it back to the columns

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, function(x)
       as.integer(gsub(",", "", x))), .SDcols = 2:3]
df
#   col_1 col_2 col_3
#1:     a  1234  1234
#2:     b  4567    46
#3:     c    23  6789
```